# Webpart updating event

Tags: web-part, development, events

is their a way to listen if a webpart has been updated. like a event reciver.

i could not find anything about it, perhaps if i added a itemupdated event, for pages that have been edited when the event fires;I could check the page if the webpart was updated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it the webpart itself you want to check to see if it's been updated ? or something inside the webpart ?  If it is the webpart itself you could try looking at the update functionality in the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found the soltion if you make a custom webpart editor panel using the class
Editorpart http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.editorpart.aspx you can override the method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.editorpart.applychanges.aspx